# How to carry out anything other than clients.openWindow upon onnotificationclick?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have successfully used `onnotificationclick` to handle actions and so far the only thing I can do is `clients.openWindow()`.

I tried using `importScripts()` to include firestore JS SDK and write something to firestore, doesn't work.

I tried tried using `importScripts()` to include functions JS SDK and invoke functions as such: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable, doesn't work.

Chrome throws "Illegal invokation".  I believe because the JS SDK uses something not available in service worker (e.g. XHR)?

Can I use `fetch()` to interact with firestore REST endpoint or invoke cloud functions?

FYI I am trying to implement a Mute or Archive action that requires invoking some cloud function or updating firestore DB.

Comment: the js-sdk should be bundled with all the other JS specified in your HTML `<script>` tag(s). From there, your client-side JS has access to Firestore

Comment: @ronroyston thx, but that's not my issue.  I can invoke methods from the SDK, but they fail.

Comment: You should be able to use `fetch` just fine within a service worker. SWs do have different security constraints though.